# I want to make the container have overflow hidden

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a image, and then I scale it with transform, then I want to put it to the container and I want the result is the container will overflow with the height of image

this is the code:

```
Container(
  child: Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.8,
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/example.jpeg"),
  ),
 ),
)
```

this is the result:
[image: this is the result]

and this is what I want:
[image: this is what I want]

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5,
  child: Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.8,
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/example.jpeg"),
  ),
 ),
)
```

Comment: some description would be helpful, rather than only code

Comment: ya okay , you should get device screen size and then you give a device width for and half of device height for this container   for get  device size you should use MediaQuery